# Regex for accept number with only one occurrence of '%' at last

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a regex that is working fine with **NUMBERS ONLY** that is

```
var number_regex = "^[0-9]{1,16}$";
```

Now what should I have to add in this regex by which it accept only one percentage sign (%) in last, that is not mandatory.

I am giving some strings that should accepted by regex -

1. 10%    //accept
2. 10000  //accept
3. 10%%   //Not Accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use: `^[0-9]{1,16}[%]?$` or `^[0-9]{1,16}[%]{0,1}$`

Basically `[%]?` or `[%]{0,1}` before `$` tells the regex to ensure that there is an optional `%` at the end.

You can try with sample inputs here: https://regex101.com/r/F6mfce/3

Comment: Okay... Thanks.. Its working.. Thanks for explaination.